# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable on a input line

Tags: python

I'm a Python beginner looking for some help with this piece of code:

```
elif exit is False and temp is ('1'):
add_more = True
add_1 = 'y'
while add_more is True:
    races.append(input('What is the name of the race: '))
    print('Racelist is now: ' + str(races))
    add_1 (input('Want to add more? yn '))
    if add_1 is ('y'):
        add_more = True
    else:
        addmore = False
```

When I run it I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/David/PycharmProjects/Eclipse/Eclipse.py", line 43, in <module>
    add_1 (input('Want to add more? yn '))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

When I comment out the affected line the loop works and keeps asking: `races.append(input('What is the name of the race: '))`(the variable `races` is a list).

I've been breaking my neck on it all night and google was no help so far. I cannot understand why the line does not work but the other input does work. .

Comment: are you trying to assign the input the user enters to the variable add_1?

Comment: What do you expect this line to do? `add_1 (input('Want to add more? yn '))`

Comment: Please don't use `is` to check for value equality, use `add_1 == 'y'`.

Comment: Asking the user to add 'y' or 'n' and then if/else with those results. y will keep add_more to True and the loop active. n will set add_more to False so the loop ends.

Comment: Some notes: Test equality with `==` rather than `is`.  So rather than `while add_more is True:` do `while add_more == True:` (or you can even do `while add_more:`) and rather than `if add_1 is ('y'):` do `if add_1 == 'y':`. `add_more` and `addmore` are not the same thing.  Your current error is `add_1 (input('Want to add more? yn '))` which treats `add_1` as a function.  What you want is `add_1 = input('Want to add more? yn ')`.

Comment: That was indeed the error. Now that I changed it I understand why it was wrong. I just wasn't seeing it at all until now. The is versus == is more a result of me trying to fix the problem. They used to be ==. while add_more worked aswell. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors and typos. It starts with an `elif`, indicating that preceding code is missing. It has indentation errors. You don't provide the definition of `add_1`, even though the message explicitly indicates that line is the problem. This is not a [mcve]. And you missed the obvious: you assigned a `str` to `add_1` and then tried to invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are a few things wrong in your code. In the else statement you set `addmore = False`, i assume this is meant to be `add_more = False`. Also i assume that you want to allocate the user response to the variable add_1. Lastly you should not use is to compare values. Instead use the `==` or `!=` type comparisons. You could try the following

```
add_more = True
add_again = 'y'
while add_more:
    races.append(input('What is the name of the race: '))
    print('Racelist is now: ' + str(races))
    add_again = input('Want to add more? yn ')
    if add_again.lower() != 'y':
        add_more = False
```